# How do I restrict Google reverse image search to a domain?

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, search

I'm using a Python API for querying Google's reverse image search funcitonality by URL, using the endpoint

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?hl=en-US&image_url=
```

My question is, does anyone know how to filter the results by domain?  I would like to only search in the domain of "myownsite.com".